# Capture the messages by cmdlets in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am running the below script. If the Copy-Item command is successfully completed, it does not show any messages such as how many files are copied. How do I capture this?

Note: I also need to capture the error message which the script is doing correctly.

```
    $LogFile = "P:\users\Logname.log"
    $msg = Copy-Item P:\Bkp_20130610\* P:\users -force -recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if (-not $?)
   {
     msg1 = $Error[0].Exception.Message
      Write-Host "Encountered error. Error Message is $msg1."
     exit
   }

   $msg > $LogFile
   Write-Host "Hello"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtein a list of copied files in this way

```
$files = copy-item -path $from -destination $to -passthru
```

pipe  it to  `| ? { -not $_.psiscontainer }` if you are copying folder and you don't want them in the count

then use

```
 $files.count
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-Verbose` switch with the `Copy-Item` cmdlet:

```
$msg=Copy-Item P:\Bkp_20130610\* P:\users -force -recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose
```

Comment: Hi Ravi, I tried as you mentioned. It is displaying on the screen and not passed to the variable $msg

Comment: Yea! I misread your question. You could use Tee-Object cmdlet also.